# bash loop with 0.02 increment

Tags: bash, for, floating-point

I want to make a for loop in bash with 0.02 as increments
I tried

```
for ((i=4.00;i<5.42;i+=0.02))
do
commands
done
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point math.

Comment: increment can be made by `bc`, but stopping on 4.52 might be tricky. use @roaima suggestion, have auxiliary var with step of 2, and use `i=$(echo $tmp_var / 100 | bc)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12722107

Comment: You normally [don't want to use floats as a loop index](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12878655/4885801). You're accumulating error on each iteration.

Answer (score 20):

Avoid loops in shells.

If you want to do arithmetic, use `awk` or `bc`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    for (i = 4.00; i < 5.42; i+ = 0.02)
      print i
  }'
```

Or

```
bc << EOF
for (i = 4.00; i < 5.42; i += 0.02)  i
EOF
```

Note that `awk` (contrary to `bc`) works with your processors `double` floating point number representation (likely [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) type). As a result, since those numbers are binary approximations of those decimal numbers, you may have some surprises:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{for (i=0; i<=0.3; i+=0.1) print i}'
0
0.1
0.2
```

If you add a `OFMT="%.17g"` you can see the reason for the missing `0.3`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.17g"; for (i=0; i<=0.5; i+=0.1) print i}'
0
0.10000000000000001
0.20000000000000001
0.30000000000000004
0.40000000000000002
0.5
```

`bc` does arbitrary precision so doesn't have this kind of problem.

Note that  by default (unless you modify the output format with `OFMT` or use `printf` with explicit format specifications), `awk` uses `%.6g` for displaying floating point numbers, so would switch to 1e6 and above for floating point numbers above 1,000,000 and truncate the fractional part for high numbers (100000.02 would be displayed as 100000).

If you do really need to use a shell loop, because for instance you want to run specific commands for each iteration of that loop, either use a shell with floating point arithmetic support like `zsh`, `yash` or `ksh93` or generate the list of values with one command as above (or `seq` if available) and loop over its output.

Like:

```
unset -v IFS # configure split+glob for default word splitting
for i in $(seq 4 0.02 5.42); do
  something with "$i"
done
```

Or:

```
seq 4 0.02 5.42 | while IFS= read i; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

unless you push the limits of your processor floating point numbers, `seq` handles errors incurred by floating point approximations more gracefully than the `awk` version above would.

If you don't have `seq` (a GNU command), you can make a more reliable one as a function like:

```
seq() { # args: first increment last
  bc << EOF
    for (i = $1; i <= $3; i += $2) i
EOF
}
```

That would work better for things like `seq 100000000001 0.000000001 100000000001.000000005`. Note however that having numbers with arbitrarily high precision won't help much if we're going to pass them to commands which don't support them.

Comment: I appreciate use of awk! +1

Comment: Why do you need to `unset IFS` in the first example?

Comment: @user1717828, ideally, with that split+glob invocation, we want to split on newline characters. We can do that with `IFS=$'\n'` but that doesn't work in all shells. Or `IFS='<a-litteral-newline-here>'` but that's not very legible. Or we can split on words instead (space, tab, newline) like you get with the default value of $IFS or if you unset IFS and also works here.

Comment: @user1717828: we don't need to mess with `IFS`, because we know that `seq`'s output doesn't have spaces that we need to avoid splitting on.  It's mostly there to make sure you realize that this example depends on `IFS`, which might matter for a different list-generating command.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's there so we don't need to make  any assumption on what IFS was set to beforehand.

Answer (score 19):

Reading the `bash` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) gives the following information:

> `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done`
>
> First, the arithmetic expression `expr1` is evaluated according to  the  rules  described below  under  ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. [...]

and then we get this section

> ARITHMETIC EVALUATION
>
> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain
> circumstances (see  the `let` and `declare` builtin commands and
> Arithmetic Expansion).  Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers
> with no check for overflow [...]

So it can be clearly seen that you cannot use a `for` loop with non-integer values.

One solution may be simply to multiply all your loop components by 100, allowing for this where you later use them, like this:

```
for ((k=400;k<542;k+=2))
do
    i=$(bc <<<"scale=2; $k / 100" )    # when k=402 you get i=4.02, etc.
    ...
done
```

If you starting and ending values are the same number of significant figures (three in this example) you can avoid the call out to `bc` for each iteration of the loop and instead use string processing to generate the decimal value,

```
    i="${k%??}.${k#?}"                 # POSIX; when k=402 you get i=4.02, etc.
    i="${k:0:1}.${k:1}"                # bash; when k=402 you get i=4.02, etc.
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution with the `k=400;k<542;k+=2` it avoids also potential floating point arithmetic troubles.

Comment: Note that for each iteration in the loop, you create a pipe (to read the output of `bc`), fork a process, create a temporary file (for the here-string), execute `bc` in it (which implies loading an executable and shared libraries and initialising them), wait for it and clean-up. Running `bc` once to do the loop would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, agreed. But if this is the bottleneck then we're probably writing the code in the wrong language anyway. OOI which is less inefficient (!)? `i=$(bc <<< "scale...")` or `i=$(echo "scale..." | bc)`

Comment: From my quick test, the pipe version is faster in zsh (where `<<<` comes from), `bash` and `ksh`. Note that switching to another shell than `bash` will give you a better performance boost than using the other syntax anyway.

Comment: (and most of the shells that support `<<<` (zsh, mksh, ksh93, yash) also support floating point arithmetics (`zsh`, `ksh93`, `yash`)).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas per-iteration callout to `bc` finally removed (for certain circumstances)

Answer (score 3):

Use "seq" - print a sequence of numbers

seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST

```
for i in $(seq 4.00 0.02 5.42)
do 
  echo $i 
done
```

Comment: That answer [has already been given](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226806).

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you can use bc:

```
i="4.00"

while [[ "$(bc <<< "$i < 5.42")" == "1" ]]; do
    # do something with i
    i="$(bc <<< "$i + 0.02")"
done
```